# Can someone help me figure out the pieces to this regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following expression in a script I'm looking at rewriting:  `$line =~ s/.*[\\\/]//;`

What this says to me is:

- Match any character, any amount of times, that match `"\"` or `"/"`
- Replace it with `"/"`

This doesn't really make sense to me though - why would we match `"/"` if we're just going to replace it with `"/"` again?

Comment: provide some test cases

Comment: Leaning Toothpick Syndrome. Consider `use File::Basename 'basename';` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually not what this expression means, the `s///` construct is the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) in Perl and is of the form:

```
s/pattern/replacement/[modifiers]
```

So:

```
$line =~ s/.*[\\\/]//
```

actually means, match any character *zero or more times* followed by either a `/` or `\` and substitute nothing in there place. Effectively removing them.

Answer (score 2):

What this means is: "Match some text that goes before a slash, and delete the slash and the text.  "s/X/Y/" means replace X with Y and the last two slashes separate the replace component.  An example of when to use this kind of Regex would be deleting directories in a directory path.

Answer (score 1):

> Replace it with "/"

Wrong. The pattern for `s` is `s/regex/replacement/`. Here, `regex` is `.*[\\\/]` (i.e. everything before the last `/` or `\`), and `replacement is empty. It just removes the match.